# Vmware problems in installing kali linux monitors mode

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed kali linux successfully and I have tried to command it working correctly but I can't connect wireless wifi it is not support monitor mode I have tried compact wireless downloads also it is not working please can any one help me

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me and Kali installed as a VM also presupposes the user has a solid knowledge of virtualization and passtrought.  Do no try to run before you can walk.